# Multiseat setup for fun and profit: hypervisors and other choices

Tags: hardware, virtualization, kvm, xen, hypervisor

I am grad student, and I am considering setting up my dream home workstation/art tool/entertainment device/all-purpose everything. I'm wondering if what I want to do is possible (and practical), and if so, get some suggestions and warnings from people who know more about virtualization and hypervisors than I do:

Aim: Set up a 2-4 headed computing station that is optimized for using different OS'sfor different tasks I do. I want to keep my work/play streams separated, and have control over the resources that each one is allowed. For example, one head would be Windows 10 for audiovisual work, media playing, and maybe some gaming. Another head would use Linux and be used mainly for data science (mostly R and Python), and some hosting for purely local use (such as running an instance of the Galaxy bioinformatics server, which I only plan to access locally).Finally, I want a VM that is purely devoted to web-browsing, probably some lightweight Linux distro.

I want each OS to have it's own keyboard and monitor(s), but ideally I want to copy-paste between OSs. The idea is to just swivel my chair to move between operating systems, or even to have one person using each.

What I think I need:

1. A hypervisor with PCI, USB, and network controller pass-through.
2. Two video cards,one each for my Windows and Linux workstations (with the web browsing VM using the on-chip CPU graphics). Obviously, a mobo and CPU that support full virtualization.
3. A USB card with multiple separate controllers, so that I can use a different controller for each OS. Something similar for network interface cards.
4. Separate SSDs for each OS and its apps.
5. Some sort of storage pool (probably ZFS based) to hold the bulk of my files, shared so I can access them from either guest. Ideally, I'd like to to be in a separate enclosure, but I don't trust eSATA cables (they seem to fail frequently) and care about speed of database access, so I'll probably put the drives inside the main case, even though that will make future migration more annoying.
6. Something like SPICE for KVM, so that I can copy and paste freely between OS's.

Is there anything I am overlooking?

What hypervisor or similar solution is best for what I want to do? I am leaning towards KVM, but am far from committed.I will consider paid solutions if there is a compelling reason to use them.

What are some pitfalls I should be wary of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. kvm will work here ideally, a lot of tutorials and lot of intel based configurations working like a charm
2. zfs can't share your data, u need nfs or samba share on host machine
3. Synergy software is for you.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I was unclear, what I want is to have a zfs pool with my files and use a protocol like samba to share between VMs.

Comment: @Thoughtcraft, btw, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF maybe most complete tutorial that will help you to configure vms for ddcnet performance.